# OpenMP consruct schedule(static[,chunk])

Tags: c, openmp

I am running this program on an 8-core machine. The output that I am getting contains more than 2 `Hello` or more than 2 `World` for some values of `ID`. As I am using `schedule(static,2)` each thread should run only 2 iterations. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int ID,nthreads;
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    int i;
    nthreads=omp_get_num_threads();
    #pragma omp for schedule(static,2)
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
       ID=omp_get_thread_num();
       printf("Hello(%d)\n",ID);
       printf("World(%d)\n",ID);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop is executed the same number of times as if there was no OpenMP. Every time it is executed, the message is printed. It doesn't matter which thread prints it and how many threads there are. The `for` loop OpenMP worksharing  just means that the work of printing the message `n` times is divided between the threads, but the number of passes remains.

Note you have a race condition with the `ID` variable. You should make it private or declare it inside the loop. The value of the variable can have meaningless values when printed. Declaring it inside the loop:

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static,2)
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
{
   int ID=omp_get_thread_num();
   printf("Hello(%d)\n",ID);
   printf("World(%d)\n",ID);
}
```

or

```
int ID=omp_get_thread_num();
#pragma omp for schedule(static,2) private(ID)
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
{
   printf("Hello(%d)\n",ID);
   printf("World(%d)\n",ID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,actually it was because of the race condition only that some of the threads were printing Hello 3 times

Comment: I see, I first didn't get what exactly you mean in the question.

Comment: Is there a way through which all the threads print both statements simultaneously without using barrier?

Comment: Yes, privatize `ID` as I show in the answer or using `private()`.